# Violación de segmento usando strcpy() en C

Tags: c, string

tengo esta función

```
void cpyCommand(char *origin[], char *destiny[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (origin[i] != NULL) {
        strcpy(destiny[i], origin[i]);
        i++;
    }
    destiny[i] = NULL;
}
```

Y al llamarla, cuando llega al strcpy() me salta un mensaje de "Violación de segmento("core" generado)" y no se el motivo.
Los array de los parámetros están inicializados.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer? ¿Copiar una cadena en otra, o bien un array de punteros a cadenas en otro? Si es lo primero, directamente `strcpy(destiny, origin)` lo haría, sin necesidad de bucle. De hecho, el bucle sería un error, ya que en cada iteración `origin[i]` o `destiny[i]` serían caracteres y no punteros a caracter como espera `strcpy()`. Si es lo segundo, lo más probable es que los arrays no estén bien inicializados, mejor muestras el código de la parte que los crea y llama a esta función.

Comment: Lo que tengo es un array de punteros a char, es decir, un array de strings, y lo que quiero hacer es copiar el array completo en otro.
El codigo completo es demasiado largo, pero pongo el trozo que me dices:
`char *args[MAX_LINE/2];
 char *history[300][MAX_LINE/2];
 int histSize = 0;
 get_command(inputBuffer, MAX_LINE, args, &background);
 cpyCommand(args,history[histSize]);
 histSize++;`
La función get_command() tengo comprobado que funciona perfectamente y escribe lo que tiene que escribir en el array de origen

Comment: El codigo no se ha formateado bien en el comentario, pero espero que sea entendible XD

Comment: Se leería mejor si editas la pregunta y lo añades. En todo caso, creo que hay cosas mal. `history` es un array de punteros a string? O un array de arrays de punteros a string? Porque tiene dos dimensiones, pero a la vez un `*` delante. Y por otro lado ¿dónde se reserva la memoria para cada uno de los strings que copias? Creo que de ahí puede venirte la violación de segmento ya que todos esos punteros en `history` no apuntan a ninguna dirección válida hasta que no los inicialices con un malloc. En este caso sería mejor usar `strdup()`.

Comment: Perfecto, sustituyendo strcpy() por strdup() ya me funciona. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: No coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, eso no es válido en cambio si la respuesta dada solucionó tu problema marcala como aceptada

Comment: No puedo marcarla porque no ha sido una respuesta como tal, sino uno de los comentarios de más arriba. Al menos no se marcar como aceptada esa respuesta, si es posible dime cómo.

Comment: @jose_rullva He escrito una respuesta ampliando un poco mi comentario, para que puedas aceptarla.

Comment: El código es un poco engañoso ya que obligas a terminar el array de punteros con NULL de otra manera se producira un ciclo infinito.      char *mi_arreglo[] = {"cadena1","cadena2",NULL}; pero lo más normal es hacer char *mi_arreglo[] = {"cadena1","cadena2"};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el parámetro `destiny[]` es un array de punteros, estos punteros deben estar inicializados, apuntando a una zona de memoria donde haya espacio suficiente para copiar la correspondiente cadena.

La causa más probable del *segfault* es que esos punteros estén sin inicializar. Por otro lado, inicializarlos de forma general no es fácil, pues la cantidad de memoria que cada uno necesite dependerá del tamaño de la cadena a copiar.

Para estas situaciones puede ser más útil usar `strdup()` en lugar de `strcpy()`. Esta función recibe como parámetro una cadena que queremos duplicar. Mide su longitud, reserva memoria para una copia, hace la copia, y devuelve el puntero a la copia.

Usando esa función harías:

```
void cpyCommand(char *origin[], char *destiny[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (origin[i] != NULL) {
        destiny[i] = strdup(origin[i]);
        i++;
    }
    destiny[i] = NULL;
}
```

**Nota** Ten en cuenta que, de forma implícita, `strdup()` ha llamado a `malloc()` y por tanto tienes memoria que has reservado y deberías liberar. Cuando el array de copias ya no sea necesario, deberías recorrerlo haciendo un `free()` a cada uno de sus elementos.

**Nota2** Si alguna de las cadenas en el array `origin` es extraordinariamente larga (o por un error no tiene un terminador), `strdup()` puede agotar la memoria disponible en el *heap*. Para prevenirte ante este tipo de problemas (o ataques, si las cadenas `origin` son suministradas por un usuario), puedes usar `strndup()` en vez de `strdup()`, ya que ésta te permite especificar un número máximo de caracteres a copiar.

Comment: El código del op tiende a confusión, ya que obliga a quien utilice dicha funcion a terminar el arreglo de punteros con NULL al final, de otra manera se producira un ciclo infinito. Lo mas normal no es hacer esto: char *mi_arreglo[] = {"cadena1","cadena2",NULL}; sino hacer char *mi_arreglo[] = {"cadena1","cadena2"};

Comment: @theriver Si, pero en ese caso la función debería recibir como parámetro el número de elementos del array. La alternativa de NULL como terminador de un array también es válida y se ve en varios sitios de la biblioteca estándar C (por ejemplo, la función `execv()` o `execvp()`

Answer (score 0):

Si te da ese error es porque al intentar acceder a la posición `i` de uno de los array es nulo. Dado que compruebas `origin[i] != NULL` el problema debe ser que `destiny[i]` es nulo.

Comment: destiny es un array declarado con su tamaño pero sin ninguna posición inicializada, pero aunque antes de hacer strcpy() le de un valor cualquiera me sigue saltando la violación de segmento